# Specific template for content type not working

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, themes

I have a content type with a machine-readable name set to 'sbpage'.
In my theme folder under /templates I have created node--sbpage.tpl.php but this isn't getting loaded in as the template.

Separately I have node--course.tpl.php working for a content type named 'course'.

I've probably missed a step somewhere but it's driving me mad.

This is Drupal7, latest stable build.

Comment: cleared theme cache? (clear all cache does the job)

Comment: Yep 'cleared all cache' didn't help sadly :(

Comment: Obvious, but are you absolutely sure you've got 2 dashes in the file name? (I've done a face palm or two when I used 3 dashes and didn't notice it because of the font size.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use [Devel themer](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) to have more information and track down which templates and suggestions have been fired.

The only thing I can think of on the top of my head is that you might have a node--nid.tpl.php overriding some particular nodes, that's the only thing that comes after they machine name type: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7